# NullReference exception when using List.Add<t>, would like to understand it

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a settings class that looks like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for pipeline settings
/// </summary>
public class PipelineSettings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of jobs to process
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("jobs")]
    public List<PipelineJob> Jobs;

    // todo: make private and create FetchCredentials(id)
    /// <summary>
    /// List of credentials information cataloged by id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("credentials")]
    public List<PipelineCredentials> Credentials;


}
```

And a credentials class that looks like the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to hold credentials for pipeline jobs
/// </summary>
public class PipelineCredentials
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The id for the current credential  to be used when referring to it within
    ///  other areas of json settings files
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id;

    /// <summary>
    /// Username or login string for the current system
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username;

    // refine: AES auto encrypt?
    /// <summary>
    /// The password for the active authentication. If not encrypted then it
    /// will be automatically converted into an AES encrypted string
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password;

    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string UNCPath;
}
```

I've built the following to try to add a new credential to my list:

```
var settings = new PipelineSettings();

// Build credentials for storage
var credentials = new PipelineCredentials();
credentials.Id = 1;
credentials.Username = "testUsername";
credentials.Password = "test_password";
credentials.UNCPath = null;

// Add credentials to the current settings class
settings.Credentials.Add(credentials);

var json = new JsonSerializeHelper();

Console.Write(json.Serialize(settings));

Console.ReadKey();
```

And when I do, I'm receiving a null reference exception on the following line:

```
settings.Credentials.Add(credentials);
```

I don't know what I don't know - how should I be adding new items into a list if they're prebuilt?

Comment: Take a look at your `Credentials` List. It is not initialized ;) Maybe yur JSON has no values for the Credentials and sets them to `null`

Comment: Public instance fields...Argh, my eyes!!!!

Comment: @rexcfnghk Any guidance on how to do it better? Would love to improve my approaches! Should I use backing fields everywhere? If so, why?

Comment: @Codingo, You can take a look at the [Field design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Property design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx) section of the Framework Design Guidelines

Comment: If you are using C#6 syntax, you can easily convert your collection fields to properties, something like `public List<PipelineJob> Jobs { get; set; } = new List<PipelineJob>();`, although I will go a bit further and remove the setter and type it to `IList<PipelineJob>` or even `IEnumerable<PipelineJob>`.

Comment: I was simply hoping to make a small joke out of it. No offense intended :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to instantiate the `Credentials` list.

`settings.Credentials = new List<PipelineCredentials>`

somewhere in the code. Or, to keep things tidy, you could do this in the constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for pipeline settings
/// </summary>
public class PipelineSettings
{
    public PipelineSettings()
    {
        this.Credentials = new List<PipelineCredentials>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of jobs to process
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("jobs")]
    public List<PipelineJob> Jobs;

    // todo: make private and create FetchCredentials(id)
    /// <summary>
    /// List of credentials information cataloged by id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("credentials")]
    public List<PipelineCredentials> Credentials;
}
```

That way, whenever a new `PipelineSettings` class is instantiated, it will automatically create a `PipelineCredentials` list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Credentials` list is not initialized, you could do that in the constructor:

```
public class PipelineSettings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of jobs to process
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("jobs")]
    public List<PipelineJob> Jobs;

    // todo: make private and create FetchCredentials(id)
    /// <summary>
    /// List of credentials information cataloged by id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("credentials")]
    public List<PipelineCredentials> Credentials;

    public PipelineSettings()
    {  
        Credentials = new List<PipelineCredentials>();
    }
}
```